# Could the Molded from Resident Evil 7 exist in real life?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design

The [Resident Evil franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_Evil) is obviously the last place you want to take away any lessons on biology, pathology or virology from. However the new(-ish) [Molded enemies](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Molded) from [Resident Evil 7:Biohazard](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Resident_Evil_7:_Biohazard) make me curious. Could you really design a bio-engineered fungus that spawns mobile offshoot organisms? Could a bipedal, relatively fast-moving predatory creature with limited awareness of its environment really be spawned from a fungal colony? My limited knowledge of biology tells me this really strains believably given the nature of most fungi, but I've been very wrong before about what is and isn't scientifically possible, and research has shown that slime molds do in fact possess some abstract, rudimentary form of quote unquote "intelligence", so I thought I'd give this question a shot.

Here's a description of the Molded from the Resident Evil wiki:

The Molded are mobile colonies of the Mold, a hyper-evolved bacterium generated by Eveline and presumably other E-Series bioweapons. While technically the zombies of the game, they are not reanimated corpses; rather, any corpses fed to the Mold provides enough fuel to construct the filaments of a Molded from its biomatter; enough Mold in an area can be reshaped into a Molded without a body, in this way, they are similar to the Leech Zombies. They are animalistic and relentless monsters who exist only to serve and protect their E-Series creator.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Sr9UByThAhY

Comment: Would you mind editing this question to give a full, clean description of the "Molded?" That will help us WBers who haven't played RE7 yet.

Comment: Wtf is a Molded, and what is RE7? VTCing as Unclear. Also, way too broad.

Comment: @Aify Resident Evil 7, a video game installment of the Resident Evil series. But I fully agree a description of the molded is needed for this question.

Comment: Sorry for downvote, but I'm strongly against questions and answers with "research has shown" and similar claims without links to actual papers, or at least "popular science" article or Wikipedia page, if these shows soind sources. Also, please decide if you want fungi, mold or bacteria. Bacteria ≠ fungi, these are not overlapping terms.

Comment: Gotta go with the groupmind on this, as I know nothing of your game, or characters, so it's pretty vague from this side.  To that - there ( I'm sure you know) are types of slime molds, very ordinary and terrestrial that *do* move, albeit at glacial speeds.  They also *do* produce offshoots (fruiting bodies) that are basically to spread spores.  Intelligence ?  Not by light years.  For reality check - no , biology - no,   but  creature design?  sounds like your game has some formidable bad guys....  good luck with this !!

Comment: @Molot In this case, his OP's claims about research are irrelevant to the actual question, which is whether these Molded could actually exist. Given that, I'm going to ignore the color commentary and leave the question open. But... Z.Schroder, the color commentary is kind of a distraction from your main point. You can just ask the question without biasing the answers one way or the other and see what you get... typically leaving the ground more open gets better answers.

Comment: @SRM Irrelevant claims shouldn't be in the question. If it's irrelevant, it's just a noise. And if relevant, source matters. One way or another.

Comment: @Molot that's why I suggested Z edit the question and remove that.

Answer (score 2):

Because it’s not a natural fungus. It’s nanotechnology that has similar attributes to fungi because form follows function: the nanobots (“cells”) spread hyphae in a space-filling curve to efficiently access the bulk of the material.  It uses some for energy and others for raw material it builds the structures it’s programmed to do.

Reusing as much stuff as possible without tearing it down and building it anew is *far* faster and energy efficient, which is why you get zombies rather than compost.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to make a bipedal unicellular organism?**

Sure, why not, if the structures exist in nature it can be distorted through exhaustive scientific effort.

**Is it realistic?**

Heck no, it would be far easier, more prolific, and more realistic to make an airborne fungus that just eats humans (like a disease). Funguses are already some of the most virulent, hard to kill creatures on the planet. They don't need to evolve hard parts and legs when they can just use yours or the wind.